# Which testing framework most strongly simulates the user experience?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I know there are other similar questions, but I would like to know specifically which framework can run test that *exactly* mimic the user, or as close as possible.

I have experience with Selenium, but have run into numerous problems. For example, it appears Selenium does not have the ability to click screen coordinates without identifying an element, which would be the more accurate way to simulate user actions.

Are there stronger alternatives to Selenium in this regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does not have the ability to click screen coordinates without
>   identifying an element, which would be the more accurate way to
>   simulate user actions.

Blindly clicking on a co-ordinate isn't exactly how users operate. They would click on an element that says "Click Here" and if it moved the next time they came back, they would still click on the element in its new position - they wouldn't click on the blank area where they remember it being.

Tools like Selenium are as close as you can reasonably get to automating what users do - but they should only be used to test the very thin end of the wedge as UI tests are always really brittle.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This question came up at work because of a real life problem. We had a bug where the "Sign Up" button was unclickable by the user because a div was positioned over it. However selenium was still able to click the button, and thus the test passed and we missed the bug. Is there a solution for this sort of problem in Selenium, or another testing framework?

Comment: Yes, there is.  The new WebDriver API in Selenium 2.x would not have allowed that click to occur.

Comment: Great, sounds promising. I'll check it out now.